# Using "line" as a geom type won't plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data.frame with the following characteristics:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
|         earning   budget    ts    total |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 1            14      3 2012-01-18    11 |
| 2            15      3 2012-01-19    23 |
| 3            22      4 2012-01-20    42 |
| 4            43      4 2012-01-21    82 |
| 5            19      5 2012-01-22    98 |
| 6            24      5 2012-01-23   119 |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

And I am using the following code to get a ggplot

```
qplot(ts, total, data=res, geom="histogram")
```

But when I run the following code I get a graph without line?

```
qplot(ts, total, data=res, geom="line")
```

I tried

```
plot(res)
```

and that works fine.

Any idea why the "line" graph is not understanding my plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What data type is `ts`? (What does `str(YourDataFame$ts)` give?)  If it is character or factor, then you need to add a `group=1` to the `aes()` when you make a line since otherwise it only draws lines per group, and each character/factor defines a different group (and thus each `x` value is a separate group).

Comment: You are a genius! this code did the job "ggplot(res, aes(ts, total, group = 1)) geom_line()" I guess the problem was that the data is coming from a MySQL table and I haven't formatted it to Date. Thanks a million

Comment: @JordanBelf - I doubt `group = 1` really fixes the problem.  Get your data in the right format first.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually `group = 1` does fix the issue. If you replicate the scenario you will see it does fix it and it plots the line as explained by Brian. I understand that there is also an issue with the data type as you suggested which can be solved transforming the date column with `as.Date()`, but I could not test that. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what wwhen is exactly, but if I assume its your ts column in the table you provided, your `qplot(... histogram)` shouldn't work without adding stat='identity'.

happy to help... just confused!

for others:

```
> dput(res)
structure(list(earning = c(14, 15, 22, 43, 19, 24), budget = c(3, 
3, 4, 4, 5, 5), ts = structure(c(15357, 15358, 15359, 15360, 
15361, 15362), class = "Date"), total = c(11, 23, 42, 82, 98, 
119)), .Names = c("earning", "budget", "ts", "total"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks Justing, actually the plot works fine when plotting the histogram, its when I try the "line" plot when I just get a blank plot. Regarding the "wwhen" yes, in this case is my ts column. Do you know why the "line" plot maybe not working? Thanks!

Comment: @JordanBelf your qplot call amended to `qplot(ts,total,data=res,geom='histogram')` doesn't work for me.  the default behavior of the histogram geom is exactly that, it tries to count things.  if you have more then one data point for each ts value, it will plot.  As far as the geom='line' goes, that would also explain the problem.  if there are multiple y values for a given x, ggplot will scream.  try adding `colour=budget` to you line plot and see if it works.  if not, paste the error you're getting.